# How to Unit Test SwiftUI Views without ViewInspector?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swiftui, xctest

How do we test SwiftUI views?  Can we test them in Unit testing?

If so we don't have proper apis to get the view hierarchy or the required set of objects for testing. We have to rely on using identifier for every object and extract the view with the id?
I have seen many using ViewInspector which extracts the view hierarchy and has apis to test the array of views matching a text etc. But is it using a right approach for extracting views will it have issues when ever the Xcode or Os is upgraded?

Is snapshot testing right approach for swiftUI views?****

Comment: That doesn't sound like a unit test.

Comment: ViewInspector creator here. The "Xcode or OS" do update regularly, and they do break something in the library quite often. Fortunately, it has close to 100% test coverage so we could catch the breaking changes and timely release an update

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use snapshot tests to verify appearance, not behavior. And snapshots are slower than proper unit tests.

<s>That said, I can see snapshots as not-completely-terrible way to validate SwiftUI views if you don't want to use ViewInspector. Such tests would check your refactoring. But the more you have, the harder they are to maintain.</s>

Snapshots are inherently flaky: they will fail for reasons other than your logic. To microtest SwiftUI, use ViewInspector. Then you can write tests like:

- "This text (transformed from the input) should exist somewhere in the view hierarchy."
- "Find this button somewhere in the view hierarchy, and tap it."

Such tests verify behavior, and are insensitive to changes in how it looks.

Comment: It's better of course of UIComponent that you just need to test the appearance .. yet the only defacto library out there (Pointfreeco) is having a terrible issue for me. the test fails when run on the Ci/CD with best precision . when lowering the precision to even 0.99 it tolerate with text colors which is unacceptable to me . 
if you know a better approach please share it with us.

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab Snapshots must generally use the same Xcode, simulator, and Mac architecture. Chances are your CI system isn't using M1 machines, which would cause mismatches. In PointFree snapshot tests, they recently merged a subpixel deviation feature. While this solves the M1 vs. Intel problem, it makes snapshot tests slower.

Comment: my machine is macbook pro 14" and my ci/cd is mac mini M1 .. I guess the macmini is not using GPU or something. how to use the subpixel deviation ? I can't find a doc for it

Comment: See https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing/pull/571

Comment: Ah, they renamed it to `perceptualPrecision`. For example:  `assertSnapshot(matching: vc, as: .image(on: .iPhone8, perceptualPrecision: 0.96))
`

Comment: I've changed my mind, and revised my answer.

Comment: I reached to same conclusion 2 months ago , the snapshot test is not reliable at all , if you changed the colors in your app that mean you need to replace the snapshots , which can be including other breaking changes to the view. that's not correct